# Android 12 Beta 1 AOSP Build Fail

Tags: android, neural-network, android-12

I am trying to build recently released `android-s-beta-1` from Google but I am getting some build errors mainly in `module:aosp-dir/packages/modules/NeuralNetworks/`

```
error: packages/modules/NeuralNetworks/shim_and_sl/Android.bp:96:16: unrecognized property "llndk_stubs"
error: packages/modules/NeuralNetworks/shim_and_sl/Android.bp:133:1: unrecognized module type "llndk_library"
error: packages/modules/NeuralNetworks/runtime/Android.bp:163:16: unrecognized property "llndk_stubs"
error: packages/modules/NeuralNetworks/runtime/Android.bp:247:1: unrecognized module type "llndk_library" 
soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
```

I am using `"lunch aosp_x86_64-eng"`. Please let me know, if anyone has any idea.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the link of `android-s-beta-1` release?

Comment: Can you also mention which branch you're using?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-s-beta-1

Answer (score 3):

Try to `git checkout a1191b55fc209e2f685c8eb788e8237280660299` on this project *packages/modules/NeuralNetworks*

Answer (score 1):

cherry-pick these patches and try:
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/packages/modules/NeuralNetworks/+/1684530
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/packages/modules/NeuralNetworks/+/1715990

Comment: Thanx. This resolved this issue. After this fix, I am getting new issue viz. packages/modules/NeuralNetworks/runtime/Manager.cpp:1015:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'hal'   , Any idea on this?

Comment: Hi @SiddharthKumarAgrawal
Did you find a solution for this issue ?

Comment: Hi, Can you check this: git checkout a1191b55fc209e2f685c8eb788e8237280660299 on this project packages/modules/NeuralNetworks as suggested by Patryk