# AOSP Android 12 Beta2 version build fails either for emulator or physical devices

Tags: android, compilation, android-source

I tried to compile Android 12 branches, compilation succeeded but I cannot either run in emulator or run in Pixel 4XL.

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b refs/tags/android-s-beta-2
repo sync
```

Serval compile errors were encountered at the beginning, I just found someone who met these and solved it, here is the link: [Android 12 Beta 1 AOSP Build Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67673531/android-12-beta-1-aosp-build-fail)

[AOSP Android 12 Beta version build fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68518404/aosp-android-12-beta-version-build-fails?noredirect=1&lq=1)

After solved these issues, I succeed in compiling Android12, but cannot run on any devices/emulators.

Regarding run in emulator, there is no userdata.img generated after compilation:
[image]

And for building it to physical devices, I didn't find any proprietary binaries from official, so I just refer the [android doc](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading#downloading-proprietary-binaries) and download the newest release binaries for compiling, but it can't run in physical device either.

I'm not sure if I miss something, if anyone has some experiences for building AOSP 12, HELP! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem when I build android-12.0.0_r3. Building succeed,but running emulator failed. I solved this problem with `lunch sdk_x86_64` instead of `lunch aosp_x86_64-eng`, you can try this:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch sdk_x86_64
make
emulator
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, already flash the rom to the physical device base on R3 verison.